# Pandas datetime matching nearest date - indexing error 'dtype='int64')' is an invalid key'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame, D1 that looks as follows:

```html
close Date Symbol ICO_to
2.71 6/12/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.18 6/13/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.1 6/14/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.17 6/15/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.34 6/16/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.24 6/17/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
3.32 6/18/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.73 6/19/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.03 6/20/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.1 6/21/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.26 6/22/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
2.17 6/23/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.88 6/24/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.64 6/25/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.96 6/26/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.79 6/27/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.69 6/28/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.45 6/29/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.38 6/30/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.35 7/1/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
1.37 7/2/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
```

I'm trying to get the returns up to the close value on the 30th day after the ICO_to value by referencing the Date column (all ICO_to value are the same). This requires matching the nearest 'Date' value with the "ICO_to" date:

```
##Convert to datetime, format   
    D1.rename(columns={'timestamp': 'Date'}, inplace=True)
    D1.Date = pd.to_datetime(D1.Date)

    D1.rename(columns={'ICO to': 'ICO_to'}, inplace=True)
    D1.ICO_to = pd.to_datetime(D1.ICO_to)

## Create a variable identifying the first ICO_to value (even though all ICO_to values are the same)
    ICO_to = D1.loc[0, 'ICO_to']
    ICO_to = pd.to_datetime(ICO_to)

## Identify the first date where 'Date' column most closely matches 'ICO_to' column value, remove all Date values prior

    D1.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    D1.reset_index(drop=True)
    D1 = D1[D1.index >= D1[min(abs(D1.Date - D1.ICO_to)) == abs(D1.Date - D1.ICO_to)].index[0]]
    D1.reset_index(drop=True)

## Identify the date 30 days from ICO_to value
    ThirtyDaysfromICO = ICO_to + pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')
    Nearest_30_day_row = D1[min(abs(D1.Date - ThirtyDaysfromICO)) == abs(D1.Date - ThirtyDaysfromICO)] ##Find the 30-days-out date row value
    Nearest_30_day_row_DF = pd.DataFrame(Nearest_30_day_row) ##Make sure it's still a dataframe
    Nearest30_day_row_index = Nearest_30_day_row_DF.index ##Find the index value for the 30-days-out row
    Nearest30_day_row_index = pd.to_numeric(Nearest30_day_row_index) ##attempt to convert index to numeric value
    #Nearest30_day_row_index = Nearest30_day_row_index.astype(str).astype(int) ## Second attempt to convert to numeric value, same error

## Find  returns from'close' value up to 30-days-out-period
    D1['First30DReturn'] = D1.loc[0:Nearest30_day_row_index, 'close'].pct_change()
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Int64Index([16], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key
```

...referring to the last line (D1['First30DReturn']). I think the index is not picking up the value because of datetime? I tried to adjust for this by formally converting the index value to an integer above. This should return the close of 6/28/2017 - 1.69.

Why is this error showing up on the last row?

Comment: Replace your second to last line with: `Nearest30_day_row_index = pd.to_numeric(Nearest30_day_row_index)[0]`. You want the index integer, not the `pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index` object.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need that line. Remove it and one line above it you can just do `Nearest30_day_row_index = Nearest_30_day_row_DF.index[0]`